# How to calculate the Manhattan Distance between two coordinates in Python recursively?

Tags: python, distance, absolute

How  to calculate the distance traveled by a user based on two columns?

Features for example:

```
  user_id     coordinate    Initial distance

        8     -2,1          0,0
        5      -2,-1        0,0     
        3      1,0          0,0
        5      0,2          0,0
        8      2,6          0,0
        3      4,5          0,0
```

Explanation:

`user_id` 3’s initial position is 0,0.

Next coordinates are -4,4. Total Distance = |-4 - 0| + |4 - 0| = 8.
Next coordinates are 4,5. Total Distance = 8 + |4 - (-4)| + |5 - 4| = 17.

```
 user_id    total distance 

 1          40   
 3          24
```

Im already tried below code it will work only for one `user_id` but I need all `user_id`

```
for i,j in zip(x['coordinate'][:-1], x['coordinate'].shift(-1)):

    print('i',i,'j',j)
    diff.append((np.array(i) - np.array(j)))
    #print(list(zip(i,j)))

diff.insert(0,np.array([-2,1]))
r=[abs(i)+abs(j) for i,j in diff]
print(diff)
print(sum(r))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: diff =[]
for i,j in zip(x['coordinate'][:-1], x['coordinate'].shift(-1)):
    print('i',i,'j',j)
   
    diff.append((np.array(i) - np.array(j)))
    #print(list(zip(i,j)))
diff.insert(0,np.array([-2,1]))
r=[abs(i)+abs(j) for i,j in diff]
print(diff)
print(sum(r))